# Categories links in breadcrumbs have empty title attribute in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

On my site, title attributes of breadcrumbs links are empty. Only home page breadcrumb link has a title attribute. I need it for seo optimization.

How to add a title for categories breadcrumbs links?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to patch \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data.php

[image]

and make it like this:
[image]